# How can I tell if a tensor equation has a non-trivial solution or no solution at all?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, tensors

I have the equation $C^{ab}A_{ab}=X^{ab}(A_{ab}+B_{ab})$. Is there a non-trivial solution to solve for the tensor $X^{ab}$ where none of the tensors can be set to zero? How would I solve for it?

If I say $D_{ab}:=(A_{ab}+B_{ab})$ is invertible then I can solve for $X^{ab}$. How can I solve for $X^{ab}$ if $D_{ab}$ or its constituents are not invertible?

Comment: Is your equation written with implicit sums?

Comment: Let's say $A_{ab}(x)$ and $B_{ab}(x*y)$ and $C^{ab}(z,y)$. Where x, y, and z are independent and x*y is the product of x and y variables.

Comment: And yes, a and b are summed over.

Comment: So your equation is *one* scalar linear equation in n^2 unknowns?

Comment: If by one scalar linear equation you mean both sides of the equation end up being scalars, yes.